# Get innertext between two tags - VB.NET - HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack, html, innertext

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack and I want to get the inner text between two specific tags, for example:

```
<a name="a"></a>Sample Text<br>
```

I want to get the innertext between `</a>` and `<br>` tags: Sample Text

How can I do it?

TIA...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have reached the anchor you could use the `NextSibling` property:

```
Dim doc = New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml("<html><body><a name=""a""></a>Sample Text<br></body></html>")
Dim a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name=""a""]")
Console.WriteLine(a.NextSibling.InnerText)
```