# Cutting text from string after matching pattern

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, match

I would like cut all text after <.br> before next <.br> and after the last <.br>, example:

```
string example1 = "some example<br>text1<br>text2";
//do the magic
int match_count = 2;
string match1 = "text1";
string match2 = "text2";
```

it's hard to explain this without showing an actual example ;)

**is there an easy way to accomplish this with regex?**

P.S. few more examples of usage:

```
string example1 = "some example<br>text1";
int match_count = 1;
string match1 = "text1";
```

and

```
string example2 = "some example";
int match_count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that does not require regular expresions, would be to use one of the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads:

```
var input = @"some example<br>text1<br>text2";
// split on every <br>
var chunks = input.Split(new[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// remove the first entry, everything else is wanted result
foreach (var chunk in chunks.Skip(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(chunk);
}
```

The output is:

```
text1
text2
```

You could then easily check if you have any matches using the `Count` or `Length` on the array.

Answer (score 0):

For `match_count`, you can use just `String.Split` method like;

```
string example1 = "some example<br>text1<br>text2";
int match_count = example1.Split(new[] { "<br>" }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                                .Count() - 1;
```

For getting text between tags, take a look at this question;

- [Get innertext between two tags - VB.NET - HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291644/get-innertext-between-two-tags-vb-net-htmlagilitypack)

It is in vb.net but you can easyly convert it to c#.